# Mesh gets resized after parenting

Tags: rigging, parent

I followed the steps in the Character Rigging Blender 2.80 Fundamentals but every time I execute parenting the mesh to the armature it results in the mesh (human) flipped onto its back and many times enlarged.

Comment: If you scale the rig apply its rotation and scale *before* parenting. Location should be also at scene origin - 0,0,0. All transforms of the rig and object should be 0 or else you might experience something as what mentioned. If you want to add images you can do that, [edit] your post and include them, see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post.

Answer (score 0):

Make a backup of the file and apply scale and rotation on both the armature and the mesh.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. I don't think that applies in this case but I am very new to this. What happens is I import the collada file that was exported from Makehuman. I didn't need to resize it. When I add the rigging, that is too large so I have to scale it a little to fit the mesh. After parenting, the bones remain standing upright and at the correct size but the mesh is as I described, laying behind it. I saw that someone elsewhere mentioned accepting the transformations and I tried that too but it didn't fix the problem.

Comment: I wish I could add a photo.

Comment: @Maurice Halfhide Apply scale and rotation (and honestly, location too) anyways.  Import functions do not necessarily give you applied scale and rotation.  I'm sure the import function authors have their reasons, even if I don't understand them.  (But also, put those details in the question please.  They matter.)